# using es6 import instead of require in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
var MCrypt = require('mcrypt').MCrypt;
```

How is it like to use import instead of require to do above code? I don't think it's possible to do in one line.

Comment: In the title you write `call a method on the fly` but in the question, you do not have a method call?

Answer (score 1):

```
var MCrypt = require('mcrypt').MCrypt;
```

to

```
import { MCrypt } from 'mcrypt';
```

Use `{}` for access specific property